# Assembly comparing instruction

Tags: assembly

This is our first lab in this intro to assembly class. I have an assignment where I have to write assembly embedded in c. The professor has provided the C code but we have to write our own assembly. The task is to compare 3 values (which have been placed into eax, ebx, and ecx) and add the largest and smallest value and multiply it by 2.

I wrote one of the scenarios and I wanted to know if I am on the right track.

I know that there will be 4 scenarios:

- a > b > c
- a < b > c
- a > b < c
- a < b < c

I wrote a>b>c.

Is this correct ? When I compile the test that the professor provided, I am getting weird answers. For example eax = 3, ebx = 2, ecx = 1 should give the answer of 8 but its giving something bizarre. Please help, thank you.

```
cmp eax, ebx
jge agreatb

agreatb:
cmp ebx, ecx
jge bgreatc

bgreatc:
add eax, ecx
mov eax, edx
```

Comment: Step through the code line by line. What happens?

Comment: There are actually 6 scenarios (ignoring equality), one for each permutation of `a`, `b` and `c`.

Comment: I figured it out, mov eax, edx is actually supposed to be move edx, eax. 

Thank you. 

I should have step by step debug it before posting.

Comment: @nneonneo which 2 am I missing ?

Comment: The 6 permutations are: a<b<c, a<c<b, b<a<c, b<c<a, c<a<b, c<b<a

Answer (score 2):

Forget about the assignment for now.

If there were 12345 values and you were asked to find the highest and lowest value, how would you do it? The obvious way is to keep track of the "current highest value" and "current lowest value"; and for each value in the list you'd check to see if it should become the new highest value or the new lowest value.

For this case, you could begin with "current_highest = value1; current_lowest = value1", then check if value2 is higher than the current highest or lower than the current lowest, then check value3, then value4, etc (looping until you reach the last value).

The same algorithm could be implemented as code that finds the highest and lowest value in an array with an arbitrary number of entries (as long as the number of values is >= 1)

Notice that the order of values (e.g. if a < b < c, a < c < b, etc) is irrelevant - you don't need to know, regardless of how many values there are.

Now, apply this approach to the assignment, where you're only searching for the highest and lowest value in a list of 3 values:

```
current_highest = a;
current_lowest = a;

if(b < current_lowest) current_lowest = b;
else(b > current_highest) current_highest = b;

if(c < current_lowest) current_lowest = c;
else(c > current_highest) current_highest = c;
```